# What does $\ll$ mean in the context of measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory

I don’t know much about measure theory, but I have seen the notation $P\ll Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are measures, appear a few times. Unfortunately, I haven’t seen a formal definition (it’s also something that is hard to plug into Google!). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

An interesting follow-up that has emerged in the comments is *why* this notation?

Comment: It means $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q$: $P(E)=0$ whenever $Q(E)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! It’s a bit odd notation to me (I’m familiar with the much-less-than usage for inequalities). Any ideas on the origin of the notation to mean absolutely continuous?

Comment: Here's a quick guess: you might want to say that $P$ is continuous with respect to $Q$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $E$ is measurable with $Q(E)<\delta$, then $P(E)<\epsilon$. That relation could reasonably be denoted by $P<Q$. Now go hardcore and make $\delta=\epsilon =0$, so $P \ll Q$.

Comment: @IvoTerek That’s pretty enlightening, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P\ll Q$ means $P$ does not assign positive measure to any set to which $Q$ does not assign positive measure.

An obvious case in which this holds is when $P$ is defined as follows:
$$
P(A) = \int_A f\,dQ.
$$
In that case the function $f$ is called the **density** of $P$ with respect to $Q$ or the **Radon–Nikodym derivative** of $P$ with respect to $Q.$ Sometimes one writes
$$
f= \frac{dP}{dQ}.
$$
What textbooks report to be "probability density functions" are Radon–Nikodym derivatives of probability measures on $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n.$

An obvious case of lack of absolute continuity is when $P$ assigns positive measure to a set containing just one point in $\mathbb R.$ Thus if you throw a die $n$ times, with probability $1/6$ of getting a $1$ each time, the probability that the number of $1\text{s}$ is $k$ is $\binom n k \left( \frac 1 6\right)^k\left(1  - \frac 1 6\right)^{n-k},$ and there is no function $f$ for which, for every Lebesgue-measurable $A\subseteq\mathbb R,$
$$
\int_A f\,dm = \sum_{k\,:\,k\,\in\,A} \binom n k \left( \frac 1 6\right)^k\left(1  - \frac 1 6\right)^{n-k}
$$
(where $m$ is Lebesgue measure on the line).

A less obvious case is this: Let the $n$th base-three digit of a number $X$ be $0$ or $2$ according as one gets tails or heads on the $n$th independent toss of a "fair" coin.

Then we have $\Pr(X\in[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]) = 1$ and for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$
then constraint that the $(n+1)$th digit is $0$ or $2$ requires $X$ to lie in a set whose Lebesgue measure is $2/3$ that of the set to which $X$ is constrained to lie by the allowed values of the first $n$ digits. Let
$$
C= \{x\in\mathbb R: \forall\varepsilon>0\,\, \Pr(X\in(x\pm\varepsilon)>0\}.
$$
Then we have shown that the Lebesgue measure of $C$ is no more than $(2/3)^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ and so we conclude that $m(C)=0.$

So

- $\Pr(X\in C) = 1$ and $m(C)=0$ and
- for every $x\in\mathbb R,$ $\Pr(X=x)=0.$

The condition after the last bullet point means that the probability distribution of $X$ has no discrete part; hence the cumulative probability distribution function $x\mapsto\Pr(X\le x)$ is continuous.

So here we have a probability measure on Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ that assigns all of the probability to a set whose Lebesgue measure is $0$ despite assigning probability $0$ to every point.

This is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So it seems absolute continuity is pretty restrictive? I’m probably deviating quite far from the original question, but is there a notion of Radon-Nikodym subderivative for measures that are not absolutely continuous?

Comment: @jonem : I am not aware of any notion of a Radon–Nikodym derivative $dQ/dP$ when $Q$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $P.$ One can speak of things like Dirac's delta function, but then you have to look closely at definitions and at what propositions of measure theory do and do not continue to apply.